# Cross-account-access Lambda S3 with access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am fairly new to AWS and try to put a object on S3 with a Lambda function, which is in another account than the bucket. From the account of the S3 bucket I just got the access key & secret access key of a role, which can put things in the bucket. I just own the account with the Lambda function.
By searching for an answer I just found out that I need to modify the bucket policy of the other account, which is not really a solution.
Is there a solution where I can directly use the access key and secret key inside the lambda function?
Thank you really much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a solution where I can directly use the access key and secret key inside the lambda function?

This is a very **bad practice** and shouldn't be used. The proper way is through [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) and [specifically for lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/).

Nevertheless, if for some reason you must use  access key and secret key inside the lambda function, then each AWS SDK client will allow you to specify them. For example, in `boto3` for `python`, you can use [Session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session) or [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client) to provide the credentials. For `client`:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_secret_access_key=<ddd>, aws_session_token=<ddfdfd>
```